# Cancel further Doctrine events on a given entity instance

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine

In order to handle some last-time critical errors in my application, I have set a Doctrine listener on two events: `prePersist` and `preRemove`. When an error occurs...

- ... while the entity is being persisted, it is removed.
- ... while the entity is being removed, it is persisted back.

These actions are executed through...

```
$args->getEntityManager()->remove($args->getEntity());
$args->getEntityManager()->persist($args->getEntity());
```

... respectively. However, if an error is detected by both `prePersist` and `preRemove`, an event loop is created:

1. The entity is persisted: `prePersist` is triggered.
2. An error occurs in `prePersist`, calling `remove()`.
3. The entity is removed: `preRemove` is triggered.
4. An error occurs in `preRemove`, calling `persist()`.
5. Back to 1.

In order to avoid that, I would like cancel any further event processing on my entity. In this case: when `prePersist` is triggered for the first time, it should somehow *mark* the entity so that it becomes *independent* from the events chain. If possible, I'd like to avoid adding a field to my entity.

Is there any way I could implement such a thing? Or maybe I should find another way to *cancel* persistence, or removal, in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to use an [Event Subscriber](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events), instead of an Event Listener and then you can easily keep track of any objects which have errors.

Here's some pseudo-code to get the idea:

```
class EventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $hasErrors = [];

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::prePersist,
            Events::preRemove,
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = ...

        if ($error) {
            if (isset($this->hasErrors[$entity->getId()])) {
                return; // don't remove entity
            }

            $this->hasErrors[$entity->getId()] = true;

            $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);
        }
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = ...

        if ($error) {
            if (isset($this->hasErrors[$entity->getId()])) {
                return; // don't persist entity
            }

            $this->hasErrors[$entity->getId()] = true;

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to implement the same thing using a Listener? I don't quite see the difference between the two here.

Comment: A subscriber can listen to multiple different types of events in one class, rather than listeners which listen to one type of event per class.

By subscribing to both the `prePersist` and `preRemove` methods in one place, you can then track if you've had any previous errors and prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: A listener can handle both `prePersist` and `preRemove`.

Comment: My mistake, you're correct. I generally prefer using subscribers as it's obvious which events are being listened to as you're specifying it in the class.

Either way, the same principle applies for listeners. If you have a single listener object listening to both `prePersist` and `preRemove` you can track errors in the same way.